# How to `cat << 'EOF'` within `su $user <<EOF`?

Tags: bash, sudo, eof, cat, su

```
##!/bin/bash
set -e
backup_dir='/home/my/backup'
user='my'

su $user <<EOFHD
cat << 'EOF' > $backup_dir/autorestartnftables.sh
#!/bin/bash
SERVICENAME="nftables"

# return value is 0 if running
STATUS=$?
if [[ "$STATUS" -ne "0" ]]; then
        echo "Service '$SERVICENAME' is not curently running... Starting now..."
        systemctl start $SERVICENAME
fi
EOF
chmod +x $backup_dir/autorestartnftables.sh
EOFHD
```

Above script is used to create `autorestartnftables.sh`,expect result as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
SERVICENAME="nftables"
# return value is 0 if running
STATUS=$？
if [[ "$STATUS" -ne "0" ]]; then
        echo "Service '$SERVICENAME' is not curently running... Starting now..."
        systemctl start $SERVICENAME
fi
```

`autorestartnftables.sh` after run `sudo bash ./example.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
SERVICENAME="nftables"
# return value is 0 if running
STATUS=0
if [[ "" -ne "0" ]]; then
        echo "Service '' is not curently running... Starting now..."
        systemctl start 
fi
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: It would be much simpler to just write the file as the current user, then move the file into place with `su` or `sudo`, rather than trying to nest the here documents. One likely problem here is that `$?` (for example) is expanded as part of the creation of the outer here document; it is not protected by the quoted inner here document.

Comment: @chepner,script in my question actually is part of bash script,I just want do it without more `sudo`.

Comment: Then you are going to have escape everything you thought `'EOF'` was escaping.

Comment: I wondering something besides `echo`,`cat << EOF`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not nest, nest, nest. Instead use `declare -f` and functions to transfer work to unrelated context.

```
##!/bin/bash
set -e
backup_dir='/home/my/backup'
user='my'
work() {
    cat << 'EOF' > $backup_dir/autorestartnftables.sh
#!/bin/bash
SERVICENAME="nftables"

# return value is 0 if running
STATUS=$?
if [[ "$STATUS" -ne "0" ]]; then
        echo "Service '$SERVICENAME' is not curently running... Starting now..."
        systemctl start $SERVICENAME
fi
EOF
    chmod +x $backup_dir/autorestartnftables.sh
}
su "$user" bash -c "$(declare -p backup_dir); $(declare -f work); work"
```

In this case, you could check if the user running your script is the user you want and then restart your script with that user:

```
##!/bin/bash
set -e
backup_dir='/home/my/backup'
user='my'
if [[ "$USER" != "$user" ]]; then
   # restart yourself as that user
   exec sudo -u "$user" "$0" "$@"
fi

cat << 'EOF' > $backup_dir/autorestartnftables.sh
#!/bin/bash
SERVICENAME="nftables"

# return value is 0 if running
STATUS=$?
if [[ "$STATUS" -ne "0" ]]; then
        echo "Service '$SERVICENAME' is not curently running... Starting now..."
        systemctl start $SERVICENAME
fi
EOF
chmod +x $backup_dir/autorestartnftables.sh
```

Check your scripts with shellcheck.